# try_again() Function is not working properly. At end of main function, no matter the entry it runs again

Tags: function, input, return, python-3.4

```
# Tic-Tac-Toe
# Plays the game of tic-tac-toe against a human opponent
# global constants
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "TIE"  
NUM_SQUARES = 9  

# the display_instuct() function
def display_instruct():
    """ Display game instructions."""
    print(
    """  
    Welcome to the greatest intellectual challenge of all time: Tic-Tac-Toe.  
    This wil be a showdown between your human brain and my silicon processor.  

    You will make your move known by entering a number, 0 - 8. The number  
    will correspond to the board position as illustrated:  

                    0 | 1 | 2  
                    ---------  
                    3 | 4 | 5  
                    ---------  
                    6 | 7 | 8  

    Prepare yourself, human. The ultimate battle is about to begin. \n  
    """  
    )

# ask_yes_no() function
def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Ask a yes or no question."""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

# ask_number() function
def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """Ask for a number within a range."""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response

# pieces() function
def pieces():
    """Determine if player or computer goes first."""
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Do you require the first move? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print("\nThen take the first move. You will need it.")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print("\nYour bravery will be your undoing... I will go first.")
        computer = X
        human = O
    return computer, human

# new_board() function
def new_board():
    """Create new game board."""
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

# display_board() function
def display_board(board):
    """Display game board on screen."""
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8])

# legal_moves() function
def legal_moves(board):
    """Create list of legal moves."""
    moves = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves

# winner() function
def winner(board):
    """Determine the game winner."""
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),  
                   (3, 4, 5),  
                   (6, 7, 8),  
                   (0, 3, 6),  
                   (1, 4, 7),  
                   (2, 5, 8),  
                   (0, 4, 8),  
                   (2, 4, 6))
    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner
    if EMPTY not in board:
        return TIE
    return None

# human_move() function
def human_move(board, human):
    """Get human move."""
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Where will you move? (0 - 8):", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human. Choose another.\n")
    print("Fine...")
    return move

# computer_move() function
def computer_move(board, computer, human):
    """Make computer move."""
# make a copy to work with since function will be changing list
    board = board[:]
# the best positions to have, in order
    BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)
    print("I shall take square number", end=" ")
# if computer can win, take that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
# done checking this move, undo it
        board[move] = EMPTY
# if human can win, block that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
# done checking this move, undo it
        board[move] = EMPTY
# since no one can win on next move, pick best open square
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move

# next_turn() function
def next_turn(turn):
    """Switch turns."""
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X

# congrat_winner() function
def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):
    """Congratulate the winner."""
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print(the_winner, "won!\n")
    else:
        print("It's a tie!\n")
    if the_winner == computer:
        print("As I predicted, human, I am triumphant once more. \n"  
              "Proof that computers are superior to humans in all regards.")
    elif the_winner == human:
        print("No, no! It cannot be! Somehow you tricked me, human. \n"  
              "But never again! I, the computer, so swear it!")
    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print("You were most lucky, human, and somehow managed to tie me. \n"  
              "Celebrate today... for this is the best you will ever achieve.")

# try_again() function
def try_again(question):
    t = main()
    q = input("\n\nPress Enter to Exit")
    response = None
    while response not in ("t", "q"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

# main() function
def main():
    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)
    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board, human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn(turn)
    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)

# start the program
main()
try_again(input("Press t to try again or q to quit: "))
```

I can't seem to get the `try_again` Function to work properly. No matter what the input it runs the `main` Function over again. Entering `t` or `q` just runs the `main` Function as though the input
was completely ignored. How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your `try_again` function call is passing the input from the user to it not the actual question.

Change it to:

```
try_again("Press enter to try again or q to quit: ")
```

Also your logic wasn't working in this function. To get it to work as expected I did this:

```
def try_again(question):
    response = None
    while response != "q":
        print("\n\n")
        response = input(question).lower()
        if response != "q":
            t=main()
        else:
            return response
```

Hope this sheds some light on your issue.